# AJAX with Multiple Submit

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, woocommerce

I currently have a 'Add to Cart' button which submits product data from an array and posts the data using AJAX.

Currently on submit only one of the three products are been send to the cart.

I was told to use .then function after each AJAX post but I'm unsure how to tie this in with the for() function and the array.

Any and all help would be very much appreciated! Thank you.

```
function addtocart() {
  var products = [{
    'id': 32,
    'qty': 2
  }, {
    'id': 33,
    'qty': 1
  }, {
    'id': 34,
    'qty': 5
  }];

  $('.submit').on('click', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    for (var j = 0; j < products.length; j++) {
      jQuery.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: 'XXX/?post_type=product&add-to-cart=' + products[j].id + '&quantity=' + products[j].qty
      });
    }
  });
}
```

```html
<div class="addtocart">
    <button class="submit">Add to Cart</button>
</div>
```

**Update:**

```
function addtocart() {
  var products = [{'product_id':32,'quantity':2},{'product_id':33,'quantity':1},{'product_id':34,'quantity':5}];
  $('.submit').on('click', function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    $.ajax(
      { 
        type:'POST',
        url:'XXX/?post_type=product&add-to-cart', 
        data:JSON.stringify(products) 
       }
     );
     console.log(JSON.stringify(products));
  });
}
addtocart();
```

[Network Snapshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/A1pHF.png)
[Console Log Snapshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QKVvB.png)

I was told to do something like this, but I can't add an ID without it been within a for()

```
url: 'XXX/?post_type=product&add-to-cart='+IDHERE
```

Comment: It would be much better practice to amend your receiving server code to accept multiple products in a single request. This will be more efficient on the server and quicker for the user, especially if the number of product requests to be made exceed the number of allowed concurrent requests.

Comment: In provided code you have only type and url in ajax call. Are you sending collected data too?

Comment: I agree with @RoryMcCrossan, convert your `products` array to a JSON array and pass that back to your server, and in your PHP you can iterate the JSON array. * REMEMBER to convert the JSON string back to an array in PHP

Comment: @KondukterCRO data is passed in the querystring concatenated together in the URL.

Comment: Thank you for all your responses, but you wouldn't have any documentation or examples on how to do this would you?

Comment: @Adam - I also wouldn't put a real and live dev site url into a question. You never know. It's older now but the MVC Music Store tutorial has an example of a Shopping Cart http://www.asp.net/mvc/overview/older-versions/mvc-music-store/mvc-music-store-part-1

Comment: Regarding Jacques's comment and your following answer. As you are using a POST request, you should use the body of the request to send your data. Something like `$.ajax({ type:'POST', url:'URL', data:JSON.stringify(products) });`

Comment: @TCHdvlp Thank you for your advice, I tried implementing it into my code but apart from the console.log message nothing is happening on submit. Please see updated code above. Thank you.

Comment: If there is no error message in the console, I suppose that the request has been sent. If you are using a modern browser, you can use dev tools and watch 'network' panel. You should be able to see what has been sent to your server, with the content in the body. Also, you should check what have you been receiving server side.

Comment: @TCHdvlp I've added some snap shots above!

Comment: @Adam Yeah good ! You are successfully sending your cart by ajax !

Comment: @TCHdvlp Yeah! But, the AJAX doesn't send the products to cart without the following been added: url: 'XXX/?post_type=product&add-to-cart='+IDHERE which can't be done as I can't specify individual product id's within the url. This is why I offically hate WooCommerce!

Comment: Haa. If you you put the cart content in the body of the request, you must not add products ids in the URL. Either you put the cart id in the url, and you had product to it with the body content, or you add the cart id in the body aswell. You don't need products ids anymore as they are in the body, in the object `products`

Comment: The final URL should look like `XXX/cart/POST?cart_id=123456`

Comment: @TCHdvlp I tried this and nothing happened, I then tried /dev/flying-bean/cart/ and this posted but nothing displayed within my cart?

Comment: @TCHdvlp I've added my entire script to plunkr - http://plnkr.co/edit/5XaE1iiwGMlICKJFHMRF any further help would definitely be appreciated! Thank you.

Comment: I'm not a php guy. Anyway, You didn't wrote anything in the `success` callback of the ajax call. The purpose of this is to do anything with the response from the server. I don't know your logic, butI think you may want to update the number of items in your cart after the request is done, something like 'N products have been added to your cart'. If this is what you want, that must be done in the `success` part of the ajax request.